# Merging two queries MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to do to MYSQLi prepared statements in one go as I need to use the `while` function for the variables that I get. Below is my code of the two queries:

```
             <?php
              $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM transactions WHERE order_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC");
              $stmt->bind_param('i', $order_id);
              $stmt->execute();
              $stmt->store_result();
              $stmt->bind_result($name);

              while($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
                  <div class="comment-item">
                  <div class="comment-post">
                  <h3><?php echo $name ?> <span>said....</span></h3>
              <?php }
              $stmt->close();

              $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT comment FROM reviews ORDER BY id DESC");
              $stmt->execute();
              $stmt->store_result();
              $stmt->bind_result($comment);

              while($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
                    <p><?php echo $comment ?></p>
                  </div>
                </div>    
              <?php }
              $stmt->close();
              ?>
```

One method is to not use prepared statements. Here is a solution that I came up with for that:

```
          <?php       
          $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM reviews ");
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) : 
          $data = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `first_name` FROM transactions WHERE order_id = '{$row['order_id']}'"));
          $name = $data['first_name'];
          ?>
            <div class="comment-item">
                  <div class="comment-post">
                      <h3><?php echo $name ?> <span>said....</span></h3>
                      <p><?php echo $row['comment']?></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          <?php endwhile 
          ?>
```

However that is not the solution I am looking for. As I am new to prepared statements I am finding this really difficult! Any help would be amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use a JOIN to do both queries at once:

```
SELECT r.comment, t.first_name
FROM reviews AS r
JOIN transactions AS t ON t.order_id = r.order_id
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about `JOIN`. What is the significance of the `t` or the `r` before the variables I am getting from the database?

Comment: `t` and `r` are aliases for tables `reviews` and `transaction` as the `AS` command suggests